# Missing symbol in linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

```
    #!/bin/bash
    FILE=$/var/tmp/filename

    if [ -f $FILE ];
    then
       echo "File $FILE exists"
    else
       echo "File $FILE does not exists"
    fi
```

What am i missing here? am getting the following error on running the above script

./installog.sh: 7: [: missing ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing a problem with this file, you are probably running something wider in context.

One thing does seem strange:
`FILE=$/var/tmp/filename`
Why the $ sign? Doesn't seem like a proper path. Remove it?

Comment: problem got Resolved, after doing the above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This error message in bash means that you have an open square bracket without a closing one. At least in the script you posted here, this is obviously not the case.

Run the script again with trace switched on (`set -x` inside your script, or invoking it via `bash -x ...`) and post the output.